# My fan is DEAFENING - Please help, i googled and googled to no avail [VAIO Laptop]

Tags: fan, cpu, vaio

**- Greetings to all helpful Ubuntu Gurus -**

i'm using a **VAIO VPC EB100C** Laptop with an **Ubuntu 11.10** OS running on it [64bit] and i'm having grave issues with my fan - it runs non stop.

I doubt that it is normal for my fan to run at full speed for just booting my system and fancying my desktop background without doing anything else...

---

The VAIO fan support was a huge letdown as my series wasn't supported -
   i tried to configurate the fan intervals - followed a tutorial on fancontrol, installed *lm-sensors* and tried *pwmconfig* which gave me the:

" */usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed* "   error.

---

I looked into similar threads, tutorials and manuals without luck - I'm not even sure if the underlying problem isn't the fan control at all but a performance issue but then again why would i need so much CPU for nothing ? **[50°C while doing nothing]**

I found out that there's little to no VAIO/Ubuntu Support at all and would be glad for any help availale; I'd appreciate a silent working atmosphere while browsing - Thanks in advance

Comment: You could have Installed "Xsensors" Its is a GUI based on lm-sensors. The problem is look like more related to hardware.

Comment: Cleaning up the Heat Sink may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

most of the times the issues with netbooks/laptops is driver related, specifically video drivers. Please check if your drivers are installed properly.

Comment: My Laptop came with a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5400 Series graphic card - i ran the ubuntu additional drivers and chose the ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver [the only choice]

Comment: how can i tell if this is properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your video card. If you have a seperate video card... try to disable it and use the onboard one will solve your problem.

Comment: i thought laptops have but one video card - i presume i'm using the onboard one [can't say i have one offboard]

Comment: Actually, most laptops have a separate graphics card and a processor. The processor, in almost all cases, has internal/onboard graphics. Try to enable them in your BIOS and see if the noise reduces.